# I have upgraded php version to 5.6 but i get curl error 60

Tags: php, ssl, curl, guzzle

I have uppgraded php version to 5.6 and i getting following error

```
Type: GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException

Message: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

i have downloaded cacert.pem and placed it in `wamp\bin\php\php5.6.32\extras\ssl` folder but it is not working and this error is inconsistent sometimes code works smoothly sometimes error pops up.

please help.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/9038475) might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)